# How to access global variables from required() file in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

Let's say I have 2 files: `main.js`, and `module.js`:

```
//main.js
const myModule = require('./module');
let A = 'a';
myModule.log();


//module.js
module.exports = {
   log() {
       console.log(A);
   }

}
```

When calling `myModule.log`, `A` is not defined. Is there any way I can make global vars from `main.js` available in `module.js`? Thanks.

Comment: Check out the `globals` object, but why are you trying to do this? You might have a bit of XY problem here (google it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use force, [use global](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global)

```
const myModule = require('./module');
let A = 'a';
global.A = A
myModule.log();
```

Answer (score 2):

`A` is not a global variable. every module is itself wrapped in a function, `A` is local to that function. You need to explicitly pass reference to your variable

```
module.exports = {
   log(a) {
       console.log(a);
   }    
}

//...
//main.js
const myModule = require('./module');
let A = 'a';
myModule.log(A);
```